# Замена скобок в строке

Tags: c, строки

Подскажите пожалуйста с чего начать. Я что т никак не соображу.
"Текст (например, арифметическое выражение) содержит многократно вложенные
круглые скобки. Исправить его, оставив скобки первого уровня круглыми, второго
– заменить на квадратные, третьего и последующего – на фигурные. Убедиться в
корректности использования скобок, т.е. число открывающихся и закрывающихся
скобок должно совпадать."

Answer (score 1):

Тот случай, когда проще написать, чем пояснить... Посмотрите, думаю, разберетесь...

```
char * doit(char * s)
{
    int levl = 0;
    for(char * c = s; *c; ++c)
    {
        if (*c == '(')
        {
            levl++;
            if (levl == 2) *c = '['; else if (levl > 2) *c = '{';
        }
        else if (*c == ')')
        {
            if (levl == 2) *c = ']'; else if (levl > 2) *c = '}';
            levl--;
            if (levl < 0) return NULL;
        }
    }
    return (levl == 0) ? s : NULL;
}
```

Полностью пример программы - см. https://ideone.com/6Vje1U